# Acronym package: Full name after each section / chapter

Tags: acronyms

I'm using the acronym package to produce a list of abbreviations and acronyms. Now, I want that the full name is printed after every new section and/or chapter.
For example:

```
\acro{PC}{Personal Computer}
```

The usage would be:

```
Chapter 1:
\ac{PC} with puts out "Personal Computer (PC)" since its the first usage. For every further usage within this chapter it puts out only "PC".
Chapter 2:
Now \ac{PC} should again print "Personal Computer (PC)" for the first usage and only "PC" for all following. Currently it prints in both cases only "PC".
```

It would also be nice if there is an option to enable this also for each section.

Comment: call `\acresetall` at the beginning of a chapter. Or -- untested -- load the `etoolbox` package and place `\preto\chapter\acresetall` in your preamble (or `\preto\section\acresetall` if you want to reset at each call of `\section`)

Comment: Thank you! exactly what i was looking for. Unfortunately, I cant vote up your comment. Maybe if you write a complete answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`acronym` provides `\acresetall` for resetting the behaviour. After using it each acronym will behave as if it is called for the first time. So just call `\acresetall` at the beginning of a chapter (or section).

In order to automate this you can load the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and place `\preto\chapter\acresetall` in your preamble (or `\preto\section\acresetall` if you want to reset at each call of `\section`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{acronym}
\newacro{fb}{foo bar}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\section\acresetall

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\ac{fb} and \ac{fb}

\section{foo}
\ac{fb} and \ac{fb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution results in a warning: `Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right` by using this with cleveref. Any idea what could be the cause? Cannot reproduce it with your MWE though and my document is so complex that I could not figure out what's causing that issue.