# Custom Case of the short acronyms using acro package (ex: PoE, LoL etc.)

Tags: acronyms, capitalization

I'm trying to make my acronym short hand a mix of upper and lower case for example **PoE** versus what it currently does by default which is **POE**

So far I have tried the `\lowercase` `\MakeLowercase` and including the label and custom acro aka:

```
{poe}[PoE]{Power over Ethernet}
```

Thank you for your help in advance for this :)

**EDIT** Added MWE of the glossary page below, the full template was borrowed form (https://github.com/briandealwis/ubcdiss):

```
%% The following is a directive for TeXShop to indicate the main file
%%!TEX root = diss.tex

\chapter{Glossary}

%This glossary uses the handy \latexpackage{acroynym} package to    automaticallymaintain the glossary.  It uses the package's    \texttt{printonlyused}option to include only those acronyms explicitly  referenced in the\LaTeX\ source.

% use \acrodef to define an acronym, but no listing
\acrodef{UI}{user interface}

% The acronym environment will typeset only those acronyms that were
% *actually used* in the course of the document
\begin{acronym}[ANOVA]
%Begin template acronyms that were not removed

\acro{PoE}[PoE]{application programming interface}
\acro{DOI}{Document Object Identifier\acroextra{ (see\url{http://doi.org})}}
\end{acronym}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: An MWE will be necessary here.  Your code snippet looks like it is from the `acronym` package but you say you use the `acro` package (in `acro` acronyms are defined through key-value lists) please confirm which package is being used.  Either way I cannot replicate your problem with either package with what little has been posed here, please do construct an MWE which we can copy and compile to replicate your problem with `POE` appearing instead of `PoE`.

Comment: Done. As mentioned the template used for the document is the one provided at the link, the settings of the template were not altered.

Comment: We'll need the full preamble so we can just download your code and compile it.  Having checked last time I used `acronym` plus [an answer I wrote using it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268253/28808) you should be able to use whatever case you want. i.e. `\acro{poe}[PoE]{Power over Ethernet}` or `\acro{PoE}{Power over Ethernet}` should just work.  I wonder if there's something odd in your template.

Comment: Your code clearly shows that you are *not* using the `acro` package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're getting small caps rather than capitals. In `diss.tex`  there's the line (with comments).

```
%% The ubcdiss.cls loads the `textcase' package which provides commands
%% for upper-casing and lower-casing text.  The following causes
%% the acronym package to typeset acronyms in small-caps
%% as recommended by Bringhurst.
\renewcommand{\acsfont}[1]{{\scshape \MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
```

Just delete this line and you should be fine.

This is a reason to be wary of someone else's template.

Comment: I'd say it's bad form to impose a formatting decision like this without documenting it  or ideally making it optional and coumenting to option.  Plenty of fields use mixed-case acronyms; they could be served by dropping the `\MakeTextLowercase` and using small caps as they're meant to be used -- if you really want small caps.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this one but seem to have missed it :D  
@Chris_H I realize now that is true, however this is the template that my institution uses (either this or the word template which is a lot more cumbersome) so I went with the lesser evil there.